# Scanf error in C

Tags: c, arrays

So i have the following C code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int L,R;
    scanf("%d",&L);
    scanf("%d",&R);

    long long int *a=malloc(L*sizeof(long long int*));
    long long int *A=malloc(L*sizeof(long long int*));


    int i;

    for(i=0;i<L;i++)
            scanf("%lld %lld",&a[i],&A[i]);


    for(i=0;i<L;i++)
    {
            printf("a(%d)==%lld and A(%d)==%lld\n",i,a[i],i,A[i]);
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

which is unfortunately only a starter of my problem, and with the print loop on the end i want to determine if the input values are assigned correctly into the arrays a and A
( the R  value has to do with another two arrays b and B but for now this doesn't matter).

when i compile and run the program with these inputs:
3 5
10 1 3 2 10 1

i get on the output:
    a(0)==10 and A(0)==10
    a(1)==3 and A(1)==2
    a(2)==10 and A(2)==1

Notice that everything puts up correctly, but the value A(0)=10 which instead of calculated to 1 , scanf reads for a second time the value 10, skips the value 1 and proceeds reading the rest of the values correctly. I'm really stuck. Does anyone have an idea why this incident occurs?

Comment: Change to `if (2 != scanf("%lld %lld",&a[i],&A[i])) Handle_Error();` to insure proper reading.

Answer (score 4):

there is a mistake in the following line:

```
long long int *a=malloc(L*sizeof(long long int*));
```

you need to use sizeof(long long int) and not sizeof(long long int*)

Hope this helps to mitigate your issues.

Comment: +1 for point #1. -1 for point #2.  typecast not _needed_ in C.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the best way to do it is like this:

```
long long int *a = malloc(L * sizeof(*a));
```

That way if you change the type you only have to change it in one place.

Comment: Are you sure? This way you allocate room for *L* pointers, not *L* items. It's no different then what the OP has now -- `malloc(L*sizeof(long long int*))`. The size of a pointer does not depend on what it points *to*.

Comment: That's simply wrong! *a is long long int. Think about it and get rid of that -1. This is a standard idiom.

Comment: @Jongware No, it's the same as `sizeof(long long int)`.  Your second point is correct, though.

Comment: +1. Guess I got confused by the `*` in `sizeof(*a)` :(